# fprintf not writing to file if the program gets a segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I am currently in a compilers class using Lexar for stream analysis.

For half of my test cases, the output is perfect and throws no issue, but the other amount seg faults.

I have added a fprintf(fp, "descriptive text\n"); at each keyword that way I can follow the flow of the program and make for easier debugging.
However, my program only writes to the file IFF it doesn't seg fault.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong, and how I can have it always write?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's really hard to help you when we can't see your code. Please update your post to show your code, tell us what happens, and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File IO is buffered. That is, the `fprintf()` call stores up the output from several calls before actually transferring the data to the operating system. If a segfault occurs, that data is never transferred to the OS at all.

Try this:

```
fprintf(fp, "descriptive text\n"); 
fflush(fp);
```

Comment: Does Stack Overflow allow for bounties?

Comment: Yes, it does. I've seen them, but I don't know precisely how they work. But save your bounty for a question that has everyone stumped.

Comment: @JamesOldiges: yes, but you need more reputation before you can grant a bounty.  See [What is a bounty?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: Cool, If you want to send me your paypal address, I'll send you a coffee

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thats... a different bounty than I've seen other places. I was gonna send a coffee

Comment: @JamesOldiges: There's no problem with not knowing about SO bounties.  However, the term has a meaning here which people will assume you meant, so be cautious about using the term.  Also, there's no way (in general) for SO users to know another user's email address, and there's no SO-mediated way to send private messages between SO users.  So Rob won't be able to supply his Paypal information to you unless you tell him how to contact you, somehow.  Be cautious.

Answer (score 3):

When you open the file, set the file stream to use line buffering with [`setvbuf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html).  When a newline is printed to the file buffer, the buffer will be flushed.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("log.file", "a");
setvbuf(fp, NULL, _IOLBF, BUFSIZ);
```

This saves having to add `fflush(fp);` after each call to the printing functions.